# How do I import into arangodb CSV files that do not contain a header?

Tags: arangodb

How do I import into arangodb CSV files that do not contain a header?

I.e. is there another way to specify the _key, _from, _to fields, and the names of the other fields, or do I have to add a header to each of the CSV files to be imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the CSV file must contain a header row as the first line because of the nature of the multi-document system.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up writing an application to take an edge CSV file that has no header and from this create (1) a CSV file with only unique nodes and (2) a CSV file for the collection with a header (that is specified at the command line). I was hoping to avoid pre-processing like this, but it seems that this is unavoidable.